# How to limit Postgresql jdbc pool connections amount?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, connection, limit, pool

PostgreSQL JDBC provide several classes for connection pooling. Only `PGConnectionPoolDataSource` is recommended to use. With this class if received connection is busy, then library creates another one.

`PGPoolingDataSource` (with `setMaxConnections` called) is waiting until some connection will become free (if all of them busy), that's what I want. But this class is marked as [@Deprecated](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGPoolingDataSource.html).

At the source code I see it uses `PGPooledConnection`, those one use `BaseDataSource` and there is no mention of any limitation.

Is there any correct way to limit pool connections?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a third-party connection pool library like [HikariCP](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) or [DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/), or the one included with your application server (if any).

This is also document in the deprecation note of `PGPoolingDataSource` (see [source on GitHub](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/ds/PGPoolingDataSource.java)):

> Since 42.0.0, instead of this class you should use a fully featured
>   connection pool like HikariCP, vibur-dbcp, commons-dbcp, c3p0, etc.

The class `PGConnectionPoolDataSource` does not implement a connection pool, it is intended to be **used by** a connection pool as the factory of connections.

Comment: That is sad. Hope someday pooling will become part of JDBC!

Comment: @Dmitry JDBC is an API and specification, it will never provide pooling tiself.The reason you need to use third-party libraries that provide a JDBC `DataSource` is simple: it is hard to do connection pooling correct and performant. A lot of JDBC drivers initially had their own connection pool implementation, but most are (were) either buggy or don't perform well (or both). The market has produced better alternatives.